# How to debug why a font fallback is used

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, chromium, chrome-remote-debugging

My specific situation is this:

Certain symbol type fonts don't load on my chromium kiosk (eg: webdings/wingdings)

When I access the web server on chrome or chromium on my dev machine I can see the fonts just fine.

When I open a remote debugging session with the kiosk I can see that the font is referenced correctly and that the file did indeed download. I can even preview it in the debugger. However, when I look at the computed font I see that it is using my fallback font as it so appears.

---

More generally, however, I would like to add more font related debugging checks to my repertoire. What other things can I look at to see why my font isn't being used?

Comment: Does it downloads the font?
You can check that with chrome dev tools / network